# Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore LoginAsync returns "code":404

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have upgraded my Xamarin.Forms app from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLStore to Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore. My authentication is implemented like this:

```
public async Task<MobileServiceUser> Authorize(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, IMobileServiceClient client)
{
    return await client.LoginAsync(AppDelegate.MainView.RootViewController, provider);
}
```

But the authentication dialog displays the following message now:

```
{"code":404 "error":"Error: Not Found" }
```

I use Google, Microsoft and Facebook authentication. This authentication worked perfectly fine before I upgraded. I tried to go through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users) but it is based on some sample project that I cannot recreate. Any ideas why this isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 2):

> I use Google, Microsoft and Facebook authentication. This authentication worked perfectly fine before I upgraded.

Per my understanding, your mobile backend is hosted by [Azure Mobile Services](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-windows-azure-mobile-services) (with the URL like: `service.azure-mobile.net`).

[Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/) has the dependencies of [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) which is used to connect to [Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop#mobile-app-features). After you upgraded  from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLStore` to `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore`, then `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` would be installed automatically.

For `MobileServiceClient` from `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client`, the `LoginAsync` method with the specific provider would send the request as follows:

```
http(s)://{your-mobile-backend-URL}/.auth/login/{provider-name}
```

> {"code":404 "error":"Error: Not Found" }

In summary, if you want to use `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore`, then your mobile backend need to be hosted by Azure Mobile Apps which you could think of it as Azure Mobile Services V2. Additionally, you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to collect the network traces when handling login operation for troubleshooting this issue. Also, you could refer to [Migrate your existing Azure Mobile Service to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services).

**UPDATE:**

I checked the source code about `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` and found the `LoginAsyncOverride` method under [MobileServiceTokenAuthentication.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Authentication/MobileServiceTokenAuthentication.cs). You could specify `MobileServiceClient.LoginUriPrefix` to override the login prefix specified by `LoginAsyncUriFragment` field configured as `/.auth/login` from [MobileServiceAuthentication.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Authentication/MobileServiceAuthentication.cs).

For mobile service backend and using mobile app client SDK, I assumed that you could leverage the following code:

```html
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("https://{your-app-name}.azure-mobile.net/") 
{ 
   LoginUriPrefix = "/login" 
};
var user=await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook,false);
```

**Note:** I just tested the login operation, you need to check with your mobile client and verify whether the related operations could work as expected. Additionally, I would still recommend that you could try to upgrade your mobile service to azure mobile app for more powerful features. You could refer to [Mobile Services vs. App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services) for more details.

Comment: My backend is indeed an App Service which was migrated from a Mobile Service. If I enter the url you mentioned directly in a browser I also get the 404 error returned. So I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: How did you upgrade your mobile service? If you just change the environment that hosts your mobile backend without change any code, then you mobile URL would be preserved as `service.azure-mobile.net`. While upgrading the service to mobile app, the URL would look like `yourappname.azurewebsites.net` and you need to change your code and you could use the new mobile SDK features. What is the form of your mobile backend URL?

Comment: my app was migrated, I guess I should have updated? The form of my url is [myapp].azure-mobile.net.

Comment: Since we could not create new mobile service to test this issue for now. I assumed that it may due your migration. You could [create a new azure mobile app backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started#create-a-new-azure-mobile-app-backend) to isolate this issue.

Comment: I created a new mobile app backend and download the Xamarin.Form project sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started#download-and-run-the-xamarinforms-solution), it could work on my side.

Comment: I just made a new app service. If I enter this url http://[mytempapp].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoft I get the following result: Cannot GET /.auth/login/microsoftaccount. Which is a lot better than 404.

Comment: Have you configured the authentication under the `Setting > Authentication / Authorization` of your mobile app? You could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#register-your-app-for-authentication-and-configure-app-services).

Comment: I assumed that you need to upgrade your mobile service, for difference between Migrate and upgrade, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services#migrate-vs-upgrade). If you have migrated your mobile service, you could also upgrade it to a new mobile app, for more details you could refer to [Basic upgrade overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services#a-nameoverviewabasic-upgrade-overview).

Comment: Wow, reading the basic upgrade overview documentation alone is a complete nightmare. I will give this one more hour otherwise I will start building my backend from scratch far away from Azure. I cannot really comprehend whoever thought this upgrade process was a good idea. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Per my understanding, if you do not need the new features provided by Azure Mobile Apps, you could just use the client SDK for Mobile Services. For new features, you could refer to [Mobile Services vs. App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146847/discussion-between-niels-and-bruce-msft).

Comment: Thanks for the update, login works now but mobile service doesn't return any records, no idea why. I am logged in with the correct user, checked IDs, should return records but doesn't. If I revert to previous packages everything works again. What a hassle...

Comment: I upgraded my mobile service but the client returns "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." The same happens when I download the forms app via Azure. How can this happen?

Comment: Where did this error come from? Have you tried to access `http(s)://{your-mobile-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name}` via your browser? You could update your question and provide more details, then we could locate this issue.

Comment: This error occurred because the tables I had in my old mobile service didn't exist in my new app service. I have added these tables and the error went away. But now I am having problems with the namespace, for which I have asked a question here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services#a-nameoverviewabasic-upgrade-overview. And the client returns internal server error for which I added a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744161/the-request-could-not-be-completed-internal-server-error-at-microsoft-windows.