# The request could not be completed. (Internal Server Error) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a Xamarin.Forms app which is connected to an Azure Mobile Service backend. I am in the process of upgrading my (migrated) mobile service to an app service according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services#a-nameoverviewabasic-upgrade-overview). I have added my easy tables to my new app service and I can see the data records in the Azure portal. But when I make any call to this new app service via my app it results in the following error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient
```

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: According to the error message, it seem that you are still using [WindowsAzure.MobileServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/) that is now deprecated, do you remove all references to the Mobile Services packages and add references the Mobile Apps SDK when you upgrade your Azure Mobile Services? Besides, ``Internal Server Error`` error is very general, please try to set <customErrors mode="Off"/> in web.config and check the details error.

Comment: I would recommend you checking the health of your mobile app backend firstly.You could access `https://{yourappname}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{loginProviderName} e.g. microsoftaccount, aad,etc.` if you have configured the login provider for authentication/authorization. Then, you could access `https://{yourappname}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}` for retrieving data from your table API via the browser. Also, you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for capturing the network traces when you call the mobile app via your client app for troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: If I enter https://{yourappname}.azurewebsites.net in the browser I also get an HTTP 500. "Diagnose and Solve problems" doesn't give me any information. I will try one last time from scratch tomorrow.

Comment: I have copied the MS_TableConnectionString from my migrated mobile service. If I then try to add the tables in Easy Tables it says: "Need to configure Easy Tables/Easy APIs - Click here to continue" If I click "Initialize App" in the next screen I get an error message that my connectionstring is incorrect. So how do I migrate my tables from my migrated mobile service to my new app service? There is no documentation on this anywhere.